# print to txt with gui python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have written a simple reporting program that exports to text files when finished. It works fine so I decided to replicate the program in GUI form. However, when it exports the input into a text file the name etc put in is simply a string of numbers. It also only prints to the main log no matter what checkbox is selected. Could someone please highlight the changes needed for this program to export the inputs to a txt file unaltered as opposed to strings of numbers? Many thanks:

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()

one = Label(root, text = "welcome to maxwell's reporter program")

reporter_name = Entry(root)
charge_nurse = Entry(root)


label_1 = Label(root, text = "reporter's name")
label_2 = Label(root, text = "nurse in charge")
label_3 = Label(root, text = "please tick the type of concern")
capacity = Checkbutton(root, text="capacity")
speciality = Checkbutton(root, text="speciality")
ward = Checkbutton(root, text="ward")
transfer = Checkbutton(root, text="transfer")
staffing = Checkbutton(root, text="staffing")
equipement = Checkbutton(root, text="equipement")
other = Checkbutton(root, text="other")
concern_body_label = Label(root, text = "please state your concern below:")
concern_body = Text(root, height=6, width=60)



one.grid(columnspan=2)
label_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
label_2.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
reporter_name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
charge_nurse.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
label_3.grid(columnspan=2)
capacity.grid(row=4, sticky=W)
speciality.grid(row=5, sticky=W)
ward.grid(row=6, sticky=W)
transfer.grid(row=7, sticky=W)
staffing.grid(row=8, sticky=W)
equipement.grid(row=9, sticky=W)
other.grid(row=10, sticky=W)
concern_body_label.grid(row=11, sticky=W)
concern_body.grid(row=12, columnspan=2)


from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
date = '%s/%s/%s' % (now.day, now.month, now.year)
time = '%s:%s' % (now.hour, now.minute)

concern_body = str(concern_body)
reporter_name = str(reporter_name)
charge_nurse = str(charge_nurse)


def main_function():
    main = [date, time, "reported by: " + reporter_name.get("1.0",END), "nurse in charge: " + charge_nurse.get("1.0",END), "statement: " + concern_body.get("1.0",END)]
    main = str(main)
    if capacity == True:
        appendFile = open("Capacity.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if speciality == True:
        appendFile = open("Speciality.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if ward == True:
        appendFile = open("Ward.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if transfer == True:
        appendFile = open("Transfer.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if staffing == True:
        appendFile = open("Staffing.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if equipement == True:
        appendFile = open("Equipement.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    if other == True:
        appendFile = open("Other.txt","a")
        appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
        appendFile.close()
    appendFile = open("Main_log.txt","a")
    appendFile.write("\n\n" + str(main))
    appendFile.close()  

submit_button = Button(root, text="submit concern", command = main_function)


submit_button.grid(row=13)



root.mainloop()
```

[my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rov0z.png)

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with examples of input/current output/desired output.

Comment: I've taken a screen print of my code. It's available via the blue link: my code here. Sorry if it's not conventional, this is my first time using this site

Comment: please edit your post and include the code using the code tags, see here for instructions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: thank you for the help. As you can see I have now changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this whole if statement:

```
if capacity == True:
    ...
if speciality == True:
    ...
if ward == True:
    ...
```

`capacity`, `speciality`, etc are all widgets. Widgets are never `True`. The value contained *in* a widget might be `True`, but the widget isn't `True`, it's a widget.

You need to associate each checkbutton with a variable, and use the value of the variable in your conditional statements:

```
capacityVar = BooleanVar()
capacity = Checkbutton(root, text="capacity", onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=capacityVar)
...
if capacityVar.get():
    ...
```

Note: the actual value of the checkbutton in this particular case will be `1` if checked and `0` if unchecked, due to implementation details of the widget. It's nothing to worry about.